# how to set an exchange property globally in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

For example:

```
from("direct:test")
  .multicast() 
     .to("direct:req1","direct:req2");

from("direct:req1")
  .to(cxf:bean:endpoint1)
  .process("response1");

from("direct:req2")
 .process("requestProcessor2")
 .to(cxf:bean:endpoint2)
 .process(response2);
```

I am new to apache camel, i just wanna know is there any way to use the response which i get from the endpoint1 in "requestProcessor2" .

Comment: is there any way to set a property which is globally available in all processor ?

Answer (score 10):

You could do something like this

```
    from("direct:test")
            .setProperty("test.body", body())
            .to(cxf:bean:endpoint1)
            .setProperty("endpoint1.body", body())
            .process("response1")
            .setBody(exchangeProperty("test.body"))
            .to("direct:req2")

    from("direct:req2")
            .process("requestProcessor2")
            .to(cxf:bean:endpoint2)
            .process(response2);
```

You save the original body in an property and also the body from endpoint1. You then send the exchange to direct:req2 with the original body in the exhcnage body and the body form endpoint1 in a property which you then can access (in you processor or else where).

To access the the property in your processor:

```
public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    Object body = exchange.getProperty("endpoint1.body");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You question already has the answer , use  and you can get the property from the exchange whichever route you want. Also consider removing the property at the final route.